# Matplotlib xticks MemoryError

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a list (`time`) filled with timestamp (H:m:s) strings and another one (`number`) with numbers. Length of both lists is the same and close to 350,000 elements.

Plotting isn't an issue, everything goes well, but the problem comes when adding the line

```
plt.xticks(range(len(number)), time, rotation=90, size='small')
```

and my script fails saying

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Documents\work\program.py", line 114, in <module>
    plt.xticks(range(len(number)), time, rotation=90, size='small')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1674, in xticks
    locs = ax.set_xticks(args[0])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 2850, in set_xticks
    ret = self.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks, minor=minor)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1606, in set_ticks
    return self.get_major_ticks(len(ticks))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1294, in get_major_ticks
    tick = self._get_tick(major=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1675, in _get_tick
    return XTick(self.axes, 0, '', major=major, **tick_kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.label1 = self._get_text1()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 372, in _get_text1
    horizontalalignment=horiz,
MemoryError
```

Is it actually too much for matplotlib? Or am I doing something wrong?
(besides using Windows)

Answer (score 0):

350,000 ticks would create only one wide line, I guess. Writing 350,000 strings next to each other will also create rather hard to read labels.

Try every 10,000th tick and number:

```
plt.xticks(range(len(number))[::10000], time[::10000], rotation=90, size='small')
```

Make the steps gradually smaller to see what is still readable.

To get the zoom to work, use `plt.AutoLocator()`:

```
ax = plt.gca() # or use the reference to the axes you already have
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.AutoLocator())
```

Comment: What if I zoom in? I don't want to lose any precision. Also, I understand that the graphical tool automatically shows only what is readable on the current screen, doesn't it?

Comment: Added zooming support. Now try with 1000, 100, etc. as the step size and see if it still works  with zooming.

Comment: As I presumed, this didn't work as wanted. My logfile has between 95 to 100 -randomly variable along the file- numbers per timestamp, so when I zoom in deep enough, the timestamps just don't match with the numbers because I do lose precision. In other words, I need to set the step size to 1 to get this work. But it actually solved the MemoryError issue, so it simply seems to be too much for matplotlib.

Comment: Looks like it is time for a bigger machine. ;)

Comment: Six months old Pavilion with A8-6410 2GHz, 4 GB, Radeon R7. I don't know how much more does matplotlib need...